# XSLT copy and change parent

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to get to copy a node to a different parent node and change the root of the xml output that i will get.

XML Input:

```
<root version="2">
<address>
    <id>300000001</id>
    <name>Test</name>
    <owner>
        <code>NWE</code>
    </owner>
    <magazin>
        <id>300000001</id>
        <kind>
            <code>JU</code>
        </kind>
        <storage>
            <kinds>
                <code>JUc</code>
            </kinds>
            <capacity>5800</capacity>
        </storage>
        <extra>
            <extra name="nr">22</extra>
        </extra>
    </magazin>
</address>
</root>
```

Desired output:

```
<tag>
<root version="2">
    <address>
        <id>300000001</id>
        <name>Test</name>
        <owner>
            <code>NWE</code>
        </owner>            
    </address>
</root>
<root version="2">
    <magazin>
        <id>300000001</id>
        <kind>
            <code>JU</code>
        </kind>
        <storage>
            <kinds>
                <code>JUc</code>
            </kinds>
            <capacity>5800</capacity>
        </storage>
        <extra>
            <extra name="nr">22</extra>
        </extra>
    </magazin>
</root>
 </tag>
```

Basically, i want to get the node "magazin" copy it in another "root" tag, separate from the first one, and place all this output underneath the tag called "tag".
My XSL only seems to copy and Im hoping you can help me figure out what is missing and how to use correctly..

Current XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="magazin">
    <root version='2'>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </root>
</xsl:template>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The output that you show us is not well-formed XML (has more than one root element). Are you sure you want this?

Comment: @michael.hor257k thank you, the code didn't paste correctly. the root tag is "TAG" and it has 2 elements "root" -> i've corrected it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <tag>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@* | address/magazin"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </tag>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="magazin"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This copies the `magazin` node into the second copy of `root`, and suppresses it from being copied into the first one.